# How to create a task pane using C++/COM in MS Office?

Tags: com, atl, comaddin

I know Office add-ins can be created by

1. Office.js
2. VSTO
3. COM

I implemented an add-in before using VSTO, after searching for the information on how to do that on the Microsoft website, I get nothing. Is it lost how to create Office add-in using C++/COM technology? I know some software still use COM add-ins, such as Grammarly, TeamViewer, FoxitReader. But how to create a COM add-in? Some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/230689 (don't know where is comaddin.exe gone now) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excel-com-add-ins-and-automation-add-ins-91f5ff06-0c9c-b98e-06e9-3657964eec72 and https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/building-an-office-2000-com-addin-with-vc-atl/ also lots of .h (`IDTExensibility2`) are here with Visual Studio 2019: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc\office10`

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for your comment. The download link doesn't work, after all, it's a long time ago. I also asked myself why I still want to use this age-old technology to develop office add-ins. One of the reasons is this way I don't need .net, .net creates additional dependencies. Since Office is developed in C++, it should be possible to use C++ to create its add-ins. But the information on this is extremely scarce, and for a while it was hard for me to figure out how to get started.

Comment: You don't strictly need the download, the codeguru article should be enough to start.

Comment: @SimonMourier You are right, what I actually need is not codes, but ideas. With ideas, I can write codes. COM technology is not a popular technology now, but a more basic technology, I have seen this technology used in DirectX and some game engine source code, but now I am not familiar with this technology. Before starting, I had to read some books on COM and ATL.

Comment: COM is still used everywhere in Windows today, and the newer WinRT APIs (IInspectable, etc.) is also built on COM.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I decided to take the time to ponder this technology.